# Не сохраняет изменения на страницах

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Ситуация следующая:

Сайт был создан на шаблоне `Divi`, на тестовом сервере клиента.
После окончании работ был перенесен уже на домен клиента, который находится на хостинге, где и тестовый.
После переноса на страницах сайта нет возможности записать изменения, но только на некоторых страницах, на других изменения записываются.

При внесения изменений -  происходит автоматическое перенаправление на страницу записей, а изменения не сохраняются.
Возможно кто-то встречался с такими вещами?

Буде благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Смотрите, может есть какие-то ошибки при работе со страницами или беда с правами на запись. Непонятно, кода нет, сказать мало что можно.

Comment: какой код вы хотите увидеть ?  если я переношу сайт на другой домен - того же сервера то все ок. изменения делаю с профиля который создавал сайт. ссылка на тестовый сайт - http://komornikhalasz.wwwprojekt.pl и сам сайт - http://komornikhalasz.pl

Comment: Добавляйте это в свой вопрос, что я по вашему должен увидеть на этом сайте? Код нужен там, где работаете с записью, а также смотрите права на запись и т.д.  - может быть настройки хоста не те выставлены или урезаны. Может быть что угодно.

Comment: Минус ? Интересно за что?

Comment: как переносили сайт?

Comment: копированием всех файлов на ПК -> копирование файлов на домен, тоже самое с базой. проверял файлы Health Check - все файлы в норме

Comment: Попробуйте перенести используя duplicator

Comment: Ох... Все наступают на одни и теже грабли, и никто не ищет по StackOverflow. А я уж давно написал вопрос-ответ на эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress

Comment: KAGG, я уже не первый раз переношу сайты и то только з даным такое случилось. При копировании на другой сервер и даже на другой домен того же сервера - все ок

Comment: Да нельзя так с темой Divi ! Гробите базу.

Comment: @klifort ты можешь спорить хоть до посинения, но так и не решить проблему и ничему не научиться, если не осилишь ссылку с объяснениями, данную  **KAGG Design**-ом

Comment: Ситуация решилась простым письмом в support хостинга.

Answer (score 1):

На главном сайте отсутствует `common.js` Divi:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще есть проблема в подключении шрифтов — пытается подгрузить с тестового сайта и блокируется.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё у вас `CORS` блокирует шрифты. потому что к ним разрешено обращаться лишь с `https` протокола. И как отмечено выше у вас не найден файл `common.js`.

[image: Изображение]

Comment: виртуозно получается дублировать ответы, может хоть плюсики будем ставить, ради спортивного интереса? :)

Comment: Я писал свой ответ когда у тебя было описание лишь о `js` файле, ты же сам видишь  что я написал "как отмечено выше" - то есть тобой.